# Why code removing elements from HashSet Takes much longer than adding to HashMap?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

I am solving this question on Leetcode. https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder

> Given two words (beginWord and endWord), and a dictionary's word list,
>   find the length of shortest transformation sequence from beginWord to
>   endWord, such that:
>
> 1. Only one letter can be changed at a time.
> 2. Each transformed word must exist in the word list.

The approach I took takes 1100 ms of time and the editorial approach takes 43 ms time. Although the difference is merely that editorial uses a hashmap instead of hashset used by me and an extra hashset.remove() method in my approach. Since the time difference is little high, someone please help me understand the reason. Thanks.

Below are the two code snaps, the editorial and my solution. They are almost identical, and difference is marked explicitly in code.

**My solution : takes 1100 ms**

```
class Solution {
    public int ladderLength(String beginWord, String endWord, List<String> wordList) {

        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
        int len = beginWord.length();
        for(String word : wordList) {
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                String newWord = word.substring(0, i) + "*" + word.substring(i+1, len);
                m.computeIfAbsent(newWord, k -> new ArrayList<String>()).add(word);
            }
        }
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(wordList);
        if(!set.contains(endWord))
            return 0;
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.offer(beginWord);
        int level = 1;
        int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {

            int size = q.size();

            while(size-- > 0) {
                String s = q.poll();

                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    String newWord = s.substring(0, i) + "*" + s.substring(i+1, len);
                    for(String str : m.getOrDefault(newWord, new ArrayList<>())) {
                        if(str.equals(endWord)) {
                            return level + 1;
                        }
                        *** The condition and content are different ***
                        if(set.contains(str))
                        q.offer(str);
                    }
                }
                set.remove(s);
            }
            level++;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Editorial Solution : takes 40 ms**

```
class Solution {
    public int ladderLength(String beginWord, String endWord, List<String> wordList) {

        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
        int len = beginWord.length();
        for(String word : wordList) {
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                String newWord = word.substring(0, i) + "*" + word.substring(i+1, len);
                m.computeIfAbsent(newWord, k -> new ArrayList<String>()).add(word);
            }
        }

        // Visited to make sure we don't repeat processing same word.
        ***Next line is not in my code***            
        Map<String, Boolean> visited = new HashMap<>();
        visited.put(beginWord, true);
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(wordList);
        if(!set.contains(endWord))
            return 0;
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.offer(beginWord);
        int level = 1;
        int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {

            int size = q.size();

            while(size-- > 0) {
                String s = q.poll();

                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    String newWord = s.substring(0, i) + "*" + s.substring(i+1, len);
                    for(String str : m.getOrDefault(newWord, new ArrayList<>())) {
                        if(str.equals(endWord)) {
                            return level + 1;
                        }
                        *** The condition and content are different ***
                        if (!visited.containsKey(str)) {
                            visited.put(str, true);
                            q.add(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            level++;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I've stated on this site before, you really shouldn't pay much attention to the time displayed on LeetCode. There are many factors that go into the computation, and the time can differ greatly from run to run. I would suggest you to just focus on getting the best asymptotic (big-oh) time complexity and having clean code.

Comment: @EkeshKumar Thanks for the reply. I did 5 runs for both approaches. Editorial one was around 40ms in all the 5 tests while the other approach was around 1100 ms in each of the test.

Comment: @EkeshKumar Unfortunately, theoretic time complexity is often very tricky to calculate. In here, a simple mistake caused the solution to be exponential instead of linear. This mistake would have been very hard to catch without the timing provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is basically finding a shortest path in an unweighted graph, and both solutions use [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#:~:text=Breadth%2Dfirst%20search%20(BFS),tree%20or%20graph%20data%20structures.).

I did not dive into too much details into the editorial solution, but your solution does not run in `O(|V| + |E|)`, and as such can be suboptimal.

Note that you remove a word from the `set` when you are done processing it, but you use the set to determine processing when you **add** a word to the queue.

Think of this example:

```
dictionary = { aaa, aba, aab, abb, bbb }
start = aaa
end = bbb

first iteration:
set = { aaa, aba, aab, abb, bbb }
q = { aaa }
In this iteration: remove aaa from set and q, insert aba and aab.

second iteration:
set = { aba, aab, abb, bbb }
q = { aba, aab }
process aba:
add to queue abb
remove from set and q aba 
process aab: 
add to queue abb
remove from set and queue aab

third iteration:
set = { abb, bbb }
q = { abb, abb }
in this iteraiotn you will process abb twice, and add bbb twice.
```

This behavior grows exponentially, each of the nodes inserted twice could add again the same node multiple times, causing growth of 2*2*2*...

The solution is quite simple, you need to be consistent, and choose one of two options:

1. Keep removing the item from `set` in the same place, but add an early `continue` polling an element not in the set from the queue.
2. Keep checking if an element is in `set` before inserting it - but also remove the element from the set once you add it to the queue.